# Change EQ to a not EQ in lua bytecode

Tags: lua

I'm trying to binary patch a lua 5.1 bytecode file.
I couldn't figure out how to change the hex representation of an EQ Operation to a not EQ in a hexdump.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no NEQ opcode. Whether the comparison is EQ or NEQ is
controlled by the A field in the EQ opcode. See https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lopcodes.h.html#OP_EQ.

`EQ 1 B C` means `if B == C` and `EQ 0 B C` means `if B ~= C`.

Try a simple example with luac -l and xxd on generated binary.

The bit layout in the EQ opcode is `B C A OP`. See https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lopcodes.h.html#POS_OP.

So `A OP` in an EQ comparison gives a 0x57 byte and `A OP` in an NEQ comparison gives a  0x17 byte.

Thus, you need to change a byte from 0x57 to 0x17. You only need to know which byte :-)

Comment: I'm still struggling a bit. My specific case is EQ 1 2 -17: If I use `printf("%x", CREATE_ABC(0x57, 1, 2, -12));` from the lopcodes.h I get fffd0057. If I manually do it, I get 00000001 01000011 00000000 01010111. And if I look into the binary itself I only find 80 C2 00 57. Where 80 C2 00 are little(?) endian for the binary representation above. Except just the OP-Code itself wasn't flipped. Otherwise it would be EA.

Comment: I mean EQ 1 2 -12 sorry

Comment: The EQ opcode is 0x17. Negative numbers in listings mean constants, instead of locals.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right. Still: At -12 is the int 200. `CREATE_ABC(OP_EQ, 1, 2, 200)` returns 01 32 00 57. Which I also get manually. But I dont find this or 57 00 32 01 anywhere in the binary. Is there some further processing of this, before it gets written into the binary or am I just doing something wrong here?

Comment: I get 01440057 for that EQ 1 2 -17. Note ISK at https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lopcodes.h.html#ISK. In the file , it's 57 00 44 01.

Comment: Jesus I finally got it. This is messed up. So you have to convert the `C` you get from the deassembly with `MAXARG_C / 2 + abs(c)` before you enter it in `CREATE_ABC()`. Why didn't they provide a macro for this? Thank you so much for your time :-)

Comment: See also https://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lopcodes.h.html#RKASK.